# How do you Binary Search two lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I know how to do a basic binary search, but I don't know how to do a binary search comparing two lists, so having a list of strings in both lists and checking one off against another and adding all the matching strings to a new list.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwVHZ.png) is what I have tried so far, among hours of other things.

Comment: So if the two input lists are `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `['a', 'c', 'b']`, the result would be `['a']`?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I mean. I was trying to say that in code in the question, but I am new to the formatting of this site.

Comment: You can't solve that with a binary search, though. Because you aren't searching for anything. You just iterate over both lists and compare the values.

Comment: Is there no way to take an item from list and then use a binary search to check it against the other list and then append it to the new list when it's found, and then move on to the next item in the list, or if it's not in the list then just move on to the next?

Comment: Sure you can use a binary search to find the index of the value in the other list and then check if the index is the same in both lists, but why would you?

Comment: I know I am not answering your question directly, but if the binary search is just a means, and inner join/list of matching items is just an end, maybe something like `matches = set.intersection(*[set(list1), set(list2)])` then `print(matches)` will do what you want?

Comment: See: [How to format code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: The whole point for this question is I'm meant to use a binary search to take two lists and return a list with matching data, so I don't think that helps, and not directly answering is better so I can actually understand and not just throw in some code I don't get.

Comment: I'll say it again, comparing two lists with a binary search doesn't make any sense. Instead of asking the internet to help you figure out a solution, you should first figure out what the assignment really is.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I've been stuck on this for two days before I came here, all I know is I have an unsorted list and a sorted list, I need to check each element of the unsorted list against the sorted list and return a new list with the elements that matched using a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Try the function below:

```
def binarysearch(l1,l2):
   return [x for x,y in zip(sorted(l1),l2) if x==y]
print(binarysearch(['a','b','c'],['a','c','b']))
```

Output:

```
['a']
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, and I don't even really get what's being done here

Comment: I think this approach assumes that matching items are at the same position/list index in both lists.

Comment: @N.E chillin is right, that's what i thought you want, then can you please explain what you want

Comment: @chillin Correct

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Also explains why it wouldn't work for me. Thanks

Comment: @U9-Forward Sorry if I made it unclear. So I need to get two lists, one sorted in ascending order and the other unsorted, then return a new list with items that matched in the order they appeared in the unsorted list. I get how to do a binary search, just not how to do it with two lists.

Comment: @N.E Edited mine